# What is one-level deep copy in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is one-level deep copy in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means a copy of an object in which the each property refers to a copy of the original property, (deep), but nested properties refer to the (uncloned) original nested properties (only 1 level of cloning)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And is there any other copy type? E.g. two-level undeep copy?

Comment: @Wei: Non-deep (or _shallow_) copy means zero-level.